# How to address to app url in django URL field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to make a dynamic toolbar for a website, this toolbar can have custom websites urls and also should have links to same website's apps. for example there is a search app in django project. website url is not fixed, so like how django uses urls names in HTML file (like : {% url 'name' %}), I want to use same name in model field to access to the apps.

This is my toolbar menu object

```
class main_menu_item(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=None)
     url = models.URLField(default=None)
     text_color = models.CharField(max_length=7,default=None)
     background_color = models.CharField(max_length=7,default=None)
     def first_letter(self):
         return self.name[0].upper()
```